# maven-ejb-plugin don't include xml in packages javas

Tags: xml, maven, resources, ejb

I have a EJB project with maven with pom.xml. I have xml in java packages but EJB plugin doesn't include them. Anyone know why?

Specifically, I have `bo.package.xml` and `archivo.xml` files, but they don't include in jar EJB final.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>moduloSigep</artifactId>
        <groupId>bo.sigep.modulo</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>bo.sigep.modulo</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduloSigep-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>moduloSigep-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <clientIncludes>
                        <clientInclude>**/*</clientInclude>
                    </clientIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Where have you located the xml file ?

Comment: In scr/java/package/subpackage/xml

Comment: In scr/resources/META-INF/ WORKS BUT in java director y not yet

Comment: Just put the xml file into `src/main/resources` and will be packaged (default)..

Comment: yes but the organization of src/java with java clases is best tha resources

Comment: But best practice and default in Maven is to put resources into `src/main/resources/` folder...

Comment: yes the resources tag , crash the EJB properties :S

Comment: What do you mean by `crash the EJB properties`?

Comment: the EJB dont package resources

Answer (score 0):

i agree

```
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory> 
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include> 
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

in pom and works